# rjags failed to load and R Failed to locate any version of JAGS

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am trying to use the package `zoib` and `rjags`. I have the latest version of R and have downloaded the latest version of JAGS as well.
Each time I install `zoib` and `rjags` it says it is successful but when I try to load them I get the following:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS version 4


Error: package ‘rjags’ could not be loaded
```

Is this a problem with the library from which R is loading packages from? Is this a version compatibility issue? Please help.

Comment: What version of JAGS are you using?

Comment: I have version 4.3.0. installed