# rjags installation error, can't find JAGS path on Windows

Tags: r, installation, package, jags, rjags

I'm having an issue getting rjags to load & run. I can install rjags, but it doesn't run because it can't find JAGS. My versions are listed below and are all updated to the latest versions. I'm also using a Thinkpad.
JAGS Version: 4.3.0
RStudio Version: 2021.09.0 Build 351
Installation of rjags is okay using the following command:
install.packages('rjags',configure.args="--enable-rpath")

Error messages recopied below:

```
library(rjags)
Warning: package ‘rjags’ was built under R version 4.0.5
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: The environment variable JAGS_HOME is set to
C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/JAGS/JAGS-4.3.0
but no JAGS installation can be found there
```

If I go to where JAGS is installed, the path is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JAGS
```

I used the above lines shared to try and solve this problem, but to no avail:

```
Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/JAGS/JAGS-4.3.0") 
Error: unexpected '/' in "Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME=C:/"
```

Corrected to:

```
Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JAGS\JAGS-4.3.0") 
Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\P"
```

Corrected to:

```
Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:\ ProgramData\ Microsoft\ Windows\ Start Menu\ Programs\ JAGS\ JAGS-4.3.0")
```

This doesn't yield any errors, but when I try to load rjags I get the following:

```
library(rjags) 
Warning: package ‘rjags’ was built under R version 4.0.5
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: The environment variable JAGS_HOME is set to
C: ProgramData Microsoft Windows Start Menu Programs JAGS JAGS-4.3.0
but no JAGS installation can be found there
```

This is the same as above, but the / are left out for some reason.

Unsure of what to try next, any thoughts/insight would be much appreciated! :)

This seems to be an issue others have faced too: [rjags failed to load and R Failed to locate any version of JAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553625/rjags-failed-to-load-and-r-failed-to-locate-any-version-of-jags)
https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/060fd5c378/?limit=25
https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/pzto5t/rjags_is_my_enemy/

Though none of these solutions seem to be working (yet?).

Comment: Use the double backslash: `Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\JAGS\\JAGS-4.3.0")`

Comment: I doubt that JAGS is installed in the `Start Menu/Programs` folder. This folder normally contains only some shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

Both of you were right - JAGS was in an odd location, so I moved it to:

C:\Program Files\JAGS\JAGS-4.3.0

And then used the code (I think / is the same as \):

Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:/Program Files/JAGS/JAGS-4.3.0")

And now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Indeed there seems to be a problem with the latest version (4.3.1). Installing the older version and setting `Sys.setenv` solves the issue. `library(rjags)` would link the JAGS automatically.